# Upload to Apple App Store: ITMS-90171 errors on every pod used in project

Tags: xcode, app-store, cocoapods, app-store-connect

When I try to upload a version to App Store (either directly from Xcode or using Fastlane) I receive a list of ITMS-90171 errors, one for every pod I use. For example:

```
[Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'UMake.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
[19:26:03]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'UMake.app/Frameworks/OrderedDictionary.framework/OrderedDictionary' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
[19:26:03]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'UMake.app/Frameworks/CircleProgressView.framework/CircleProgressView' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
[19:26:03]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'UMake.app/Frameworks/AssociatedValues.framework/AssociatedValues' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
[19:26:03]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'UMake.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
[19:26:03]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'UMake.app/Frameworks/SOCKit.framework/SOCKit' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
```

The following is the Podfile I use:

```
'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods

    pod 'CocoaHTTPServer'

    pod 'AFNetworking'#, '~> 3.1.0'
    pod 'RestKit'#, '~> 0.27.1'

    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'#, '3.2.0'
    pod 'NLTHTTPStubServer'#, '~> 0.4.0'

    pod 'GoogleSignIn'#, '~> 4.0.2'

    pod 'Typhoon', '~> 3.5.1'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.23.0'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.23.0'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.23.0'
    pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'#, '~> 4.1.0'

    pod 'MagicalRecord'#, '~> 2.3.2'

    pod 'Reachability'#, '~> 3.2'

    pod 'Instabug'#, '~> 7.3.2'

    pod 'UIView+Copy'#, '~> 0.0.8'

    pod 'MBProgressHUD'#, '~> 1.0.0'

    pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', '1.0.1.k'

    pod 'pop'#, '~> 1.0.9'

    pod 'UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout'#, '~> 1.0.2'

    pod 'LruCache'#, '~> 0.1'

#    pod 'RFQuiltLayout', :path => 'Sp§edr/EmbeddedFrameworks/RFQuiltLayout'

    pod 'Mixpanel'#, '~-> 3.1.5'

    pod 'CircleProgressView'#, '~> 1.1.2'
    pod 'KDCircularProgress'#, '~> 1.5.2'

    pod 'Fabric'#, '~> 1.6.11'
    pod 'Crashlytics'#, '~> 3.8.4'
    pod 'TwitterKit'#, '~> 3.0.3'
    pod 'TwitterCore'#, '~> 3.0.0'

    pod 'OrderedDictionary'#, '~> 1.4'

    pod 'Fingertips'#, '~> 0.5.0'

    pod 'MenuItemKit'#, '~> 2.0.2'

    pod 'ObjectMapper'#, '~> 2.2.6'

    pod 'R.swift'#, '~> 3.3.0'

    pod 'SwiftyJSON'#, '~> 3.1.4'

    pod 'AsyncSwift'#, '~> 2.0.1'

    pod 'AwesomeCache', :git => 'https://github.com/aschuch/AwesomeCache.git'

    pod 'MKDropdownMenu'#, '~> 1.4'

    pod 'AssociatedValues'#, '~> 3.0.0'

    pod 'ZendeskSDK', '~> 1.9.2.2'

    pod 'Cartography'#, '~> 1.1.0'

    pod 'OneSignal'#, '~> 2.5.4'

    pod 'BlueCapKit'#, '~> 0.5.3'

    pod 'UILabel+Copyable', '~> 1.0.1'

    pod 'Analytics'#, '~> 3.6.1'

    pod 'Amplitude-iOS'#, '~> 3.14.1'

    pod 'Outbound'#, '~> 1.0.3'

    pod 'AlgoliaSearch-Client-Swift'#, '~> 4.8.1'

    pod 'PinterestSDK'

    pod 'Zip'

    pod 'THLabel'
end

target 'App' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'AppTests' do
    shared_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
            configuration.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = "3.0"

            configuration.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'DD_LEGACY_MACROS=1']

        end
    end
end
```

This is a new problem that appeared in the last few weeks. I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and cocoapods 1.3.0.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? I'm guessing it may have been a bug with the CocoaPods version, as CocoaPods now properly sets all of the build settings (at least for me)